# arguments.length works but not argument[0].value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a value of the response
I check arguments.length and it says `1` and works
but when I do `arguments[0].value` or `arguments[0].responseText` it doesn't work... it says `undefined`.... how do I get the values?

Comment: Response from what? Is it an AJAX call that you are making? Can you show the code that you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's enough information in this question to properly answer you... but I'm guessing that the `arguments` list isn't of the type you think it is. `arguments[0]` probably just doesn't have a `value` or `responseText` attributes.

Download and install Firebug for Firefox and then `console.log(arguments[0])` or just `arguments`. See what properties it *actually* has. (or just `alert` it)

Comment: alert(arguments[0]); gives me [object object]
how can I find the value of the object?
thanks

Comment: The "value" of the object IS [object Object] unless the default `toString()` method is overridden. If you want more info you can query the `constructor` property, but you really should already know *something* about values/objects passed to your function.

Comment: @OP: Then try `alert(arguments[0].value)`, although it'll probably tell you `undefined` again. Like I said, install FF/Firebug or at least give us some more info in your question. How are we supposed to know what "arguments" is?